# C - interact with terminal so that command is written on terminal but not executed

Tags: c

so i have

```
system("clear");
printf( "Enter a value :");`
int c = getchar();
```

which results in the terminal asking for a character this way

```
Enter a value:
```

What i want is the program to suggest a value as if the user had typed the value but didn't press enter, like this:

```
Enter a value: 5
```

Then the user can press enter and `getchar()` will receive `5` or backspace the `5` and input whatever value they want

Is this possible?

Comment: `srand (time (NULL)); int val = rand() % 50; printf ("Enter a value: %d", val);` will work. (include the `stdlib.h` and `time.h` headers)  As mentioned below, you would have to then `scanf` a value and replace the number initially shown.

Comment: You cannot usually erase a character written to `stdout` by filling `stdin` with `'\b'` from the console. What you can however do is read input character by character and then erase some characters if the input is `'\b'`. I can write an answer demo ing the same.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin That is not what he wants (as far as I understand).

Comment: The conventional way is to have a default value set and notify the user of it. When the user only presses enter, then this value will be used, otherwise the supplied one. If you can live with that, I would suggest you do it this way, because your approach is complicated.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya - yes, I see what you are saying and added a reference to your comment in my original. I also agree with @redxef approach to show a default, e.g. `printf ("Enter a value (default: 5): ");` (the default could be randomly generated if that is the point)

Comment: @KamiKaze most systems and terminals support erasing by putting `'\b'` in `stdout`

Comment: a much better method (from the point of view of the user) is to output the default value, then output the ascii terminal control sequence to move the cursor to the left of the default value, Then the user can just press 'enter' or they can type in a different value and press enter.  The program uses a portable method like: `getchar()` to input the value, if the first input char is '\n' then use the default value, other wise continue to call `getchar()` until a '\n' is input, while accumulating the keypresses from the user.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way you can do it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
        char input[100] = "5";
        int pos = 1;
        int c_read = 0;
        printf("Enter a value: 5");
        while (1){
                c_read = getch();
                if (c_read == 13 || c_read == -1){
                       printf("\n");
                       break;
                }
                if (c_read == 8){
                        if(pos == 0)
                                continue;
                        pos--;
                        input[pos] = '\0';
                        printf("\b \b");
                }else{
                        if (pos == 99)
                            continue;  
                        printf("%c", c_read);
                        input[pos] = c_read;
                        pos++;
                        input[pos] = '\0';
                }
         }
         printf("You entered %s\n", input);
}
```

Ofcourse this uses the god awful `getch`. You can find that in the `ncurses` library on Linux and comes with MinGW on windows.

You could replace `getch` with alternative implementation to read characters from the keyboard.

Also I am leaving it to you to convert the string to number before using.

PS: You might also have to put a `fflush(stdout)` after every print if it is being buffered for you and changes are not reflecting.